# Does every enemy type have the possibility of being elite?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been playing a lot of Diablo 3 lately. I've noticed that some enemies seem more likely to have elite counterparts than others. For example, in Act 1 there seem to be a lot of goat men elites and champions whereas I have never seen any tree elites or champions.

Does every enemy have an elite counterpart? Are some just more likely than others based on location? If not, which kinds of enemies aren't ever seen in game as elite?

Comment: I do not think so. Especially immobile enemies like the spitting things on the wall in some caves cannot be elite.

Comment: I don't think I've seen a mallet lord elite either, though that would be extremely scary on inferno mode

Comment: I've seen that once before I believe, unless I'm thinking of three normals together.

Comment: i also haven't seen elite worms (in the caves in A2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Walking Tree **unique**](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/The_Old_Man) in Act 1, but I don't think they can be [elites](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Elite_Monsters). However, there are also mobs such as Fanatics (the exploding guys in Act 3) who have a low possibility of spawning elite versions.

Diablo has several achievements [The Takedown](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/The_Takedown), [Not So Tough Now](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Not_So_Tough_Now), [Champion's Collection](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Champion%27s_Collection), [We Are the Champions](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/We_Are_the_Champions), [Keep It Rare](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Keep_It_Rare), [Rarin' to Go](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Rarin%27_to_Go), [A Rare Phenomenon](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/A_Rare_Phenomenon), [Trophy Hunting](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Trophy_Hunting), [Never Seen that Before](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Never_Seen_that_Before), [Special Snowflakes](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Special_Snowflakes), and [A Unique Collection](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/A_Unique_Collection) for killing [champion](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Champion_Monsters), [rare](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Rare_Monsters), and [unique](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Unique_Monsters) enemies of each type - that should give you a complete list of which mobs ***can*** have elites, and by extension identify those not on the list that ***can't*** be boss/elite. As far as I know, there is no enemy which can only spawn as elite or boss versions but not both. Obviously, this is not true for uniques considering the tree encounter.

Some enemies that cannot be elite:

- Shadows
- Wall spitters
- [Rockworms](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Rockworm) (there is a unique, [Shaitan the Brood Mother](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Shaitan_the_Broodmother))

@yx.: [Mallet Lords](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Mallet_Lord) can be champions and rares as they're listed in the achievements, though they're one of the few that I haven't killed yet. I expect it's a combination of rarity of the mob itself and since everyone prefers to farm the other acts to avoid off-screen charges & easier to find NV stacks.